# How to log sql queries made by DbContext?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, architecture, dbcontext, asp.net-core-3.0

In `ConfigureServices` I prepare `DbContext` by using `services.AddDbContext` and I would like to pass `ILoggerFactory` into it with `.UseLoggerFactory(...)`. But the first time I can get `ILoggerFactory` is here

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
```

and `Configure` is called later than `ConfigureServices`. Sure, I can create a logger factory myself in `ConfigureServices`, but this is strange that I need to it if such functionality has been provided with the framework.

I'm looking for an architecturally proper approach to establish logging including logging from `DbContext`.

Comment: Notes for the future answer: *Try to use ApplicationServices. This looks like Service Locator anti-pattern but it is OK to use it in ConfigureServices.*

Answer (score 0):

Usually we create a singleton/global instance of a LoggerFactory instance of the LoggerFactory and then tie it with a DbContext , then pass the object in the `optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory()` method :

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddConsole(); });

    public SchoolContext():base()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)  //tie-up DbContext with LoggerFactory object
            .UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3